# Headless browser without server installation for multithreads application

Tags: .net, browser, web-scraping, headless, browser-automation

Please suggest headless browser for multithread application from this list, that has all features listed below:

- [WebKit.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/).
- [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
- [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/)

It **must** has next features:

- Working **without any server installation**. I need just simple library
  to distribute with my application.
- **Ajax/HTML 5 support**. Ability to work with pages elements: find and read attributes through
  internal/external (SGMLReader) XML, or using API to click buttons,
  fill forms, etc.
- Correctly cookies container (correctly working with **multiple cookies response** and storing cookies during all session)
- **Customizable browser line** (even selecting Chrome/Firefox is enough)
- **Multithread**. So no static cookies container or smth. else. I need be
  able to login and working with same site under 2-100000 different
  users.
- **Fast working**
- **Working with https** by using insecure SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) which is a headless browser and connect to it with Selenium WebDriver ([how?](http://michael-whelan.net/using-phantomjs-with-webdriver)). PhantomJS is based on Webkit so it has fast and native support for latest web standards.

Although for .Net guys it might be easier to use [SimpleBrowser](https://github.com/axefrog/SimpleBrowser) which is fully implemented using C#, i have no idea about the performance and support of standards.

Comment: PhantomJS is the best solution. SimpleBrowser not work with Javascript, so it's not a solution.